# Gaming PC Shutdown while gaming (GPU > 80°C)

Tags: cpu, power-supply, gpu, gaming, overheating

Some random French guy here, I have since **June 2015** the following computer :

- CPU Quad-Core Intel Core i7 4th Gen (Intel Core i7-4790K (4.0 GHz
  / 4.4 GHz Turbo - Cache 8 Mo)
- Motherboard Gigabyte GA-Z97X-Gaming 3 (Intel Z97 Express)
- 16 Go RAM DDR3 1600 MHz
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970 4Go
- SSD 240 Go Serial ATA 6Gb/s
- HDD Seagate Barracuda 7200.14 SATA 6Gb/s 1 To
- NZXT Phantom Case
- PSU 650W LDLC QS-650+ Quality Select 80PLUS Gold
- Fan for CPU Noctua NH-U12P SE2

(If needed, bought from this website, but it's in French > https://www.ldlc.com/fiche/PB00100625.html)

No problem back then, this PC is quite powerful and all, but since some weeks, it restarts when gaming, like a security overheating or else.

I've made multiple tests, and here what I've found so far:

- **CPU** is always **under 50°C**, even under 40°C most of the time, during gaming too.
- **GPU** is **increasing to 80°** pretty quickly (less than 1mn), and cannot go over since the computer force a shutdown.
- I don't see any anomaly with the fans, I've boosted them to full speed, and can see/hear the difference
- I've made a **full clean up** of the **hardware**, even **dismounted PSU** to clean everything.

While I first thought it could be the GPU, I don't really think so, because I've ran **FurMark** to benchmark the GPU like hell, up to **83°C for several minutes**, and **nothing happened**, computer was fine, no shutdown or reboot for overheating.
And when I was playing (Elite Dangerous mainly, no problem for 2 years), when GPU was going over **80°C**, PC would shutdown, but yesterday, during game loading, GPU was around **65°C**, and it crashed too.

So now I think it could be a **PSU** problem, but from that, I don't really know how to check (I have a multimeter, but I'm not an elec guy, just a developer).

Also, even if I don't think it, maybe it's a software problem, I've formatted my computer yesterday evening, I'll do some new tests this evening (*UTC+01*).

Also, I've ordered some thermal paste, dunno if my GPU has by default, even though, I'll check that and replace/add it, cannot be worse with it (I should just change to a 1080Ti, meh).

Dunno what more I could do, I'm here to seek your help! =)

Comment: I would guess PSU as well based on what you've ruled out so far.  You might try running FurMark at the same time as a CPU test like Prime95 to see if the increased draw of GPU and CPU simultaneously causes the shutdown.  If you have a way to track wattage from your wall mains (like a [Kill-a-watt](http://a.co/5TabZ4e)), you could see if it only occurs above a certain wattage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, problem has been solved, so here were my problems:

- **PSU** was indeed **failing**, but after getting a new one from my supplier, computer now couldn't even boot.
- So the other problem was **RAM**, one of them was completely **dead**. Removed it and since computer works like a charm.